# Link test for pooled logistic regression

Tags: pooling, misspecification

After logistic regression of the cross-sectional data sets, link test _hatsq shows insignificant. However, when I pool the same two data sets, the link test using the same set of variables regression gives significant _hatsq which shows specification error in the pooled data regression. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also define the tests you are using.  I suspect they are tests that have too many degrees of freedom for p-values to be trustworthy.